# Blazor - should I read in my data in OnInitializedAsync() or OnAfterRenderAsync(true)

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

When my page loads, generally I am hitting the database to get the data for that page. It's not a ton of data so not the end of the world if I read it twice, but better to read it once.

The page can render without this data, but it's going to look very empty/sparse if it's viewed without the data. Not wrong, no errors, but empty.

So, when is the suggested place to load the data for the page? And if it's `OnInitializedAsync()`, should I have a boolean so I load the first time and subsequent times I know I already have it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- `OnInitializedAsync` is only called once (per component/page). You don't have to do anything special. This is the 'normal' event to load data. Check the FetchData page in the starter templates.
- `OnParametersSetAsync` will be called for each parameter change, it is called at least once.
- `OnAfterRenderAsync(true)` is also called once but you are then certain an empty page is already rendered. It works but is not a good idea.

See [this picture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/lifecycle?view=aspnetcore-7.0#lifecycle-events)

Comment: I was ready to swear that I've had it hit `OnInitializedAsync()` multiple times in the debugger. But I just tried on multiple pages and it was just once. So it might have been some weirdness with the debugger.

Comment: @DavidThielen - You're seeing  - OnInitializedAsync() is only called once on each component instance.  If you're see multiples then the Renderer is creating multiple instances  - such as within an `@if...` block in the parent,

Comment: Of course Server Pre-Rendering is the exception where OnInitialized/OnInitializedAsync will be called twice.

Comment: @MisterMagoo - but on two distinct instances afaik. So any of the alternatives would be called twice as well.

Comment: Not *any* - `OnAfterRender(Async)(FirstRender: true)` is not called during pre-rendering

Comment: I think you meant "Not all". I didn't know this, you could make it an answer. But it's complicated, you may want to prerender _with_ data.

Comment: Blazor apps that prerender their content on the server call OnInitializedAsync twice:

Once when the component is initially rendered statically as part of the page.
A second time when the browser renders the component. Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/lifecycle?view=aspnetcore-7.0

Comment: @Jafin - but it is still called once per instance. So prerendering does not matter here.

Comment: I'm new to Blazor and this is blowing my mind.  It doesn't seem like there's a good way to mitigate the inefficiencies of the double calls.  I'm not sure what I'm missing.

Answer (score 5):

This answer is in addition to that of @HH to add a little meat.

There are two sequences:

On first load:

1. OnInitialized
2. OnInitializedAsync
3. OnParametersSet
4. OnParametersSetAsync

On subsequent loads:

1. OnParametersSet
2. OnParametersSetAsync

Each sequence either renders the component once or twice.

If there's no yield in either of the async methods, the comonent renders at the end of the sequence.

If either or both yield, the component renders on the first yield.

Therefore, if your code is true async and yields when it makes a backend call to get the data, your component must handle the default state of the data in the component or the injected presentation layer service.

For example using `private IEnumerable _weather;` and populating it asynchronously, you should either:

1. Check for a null and don't render the content if it's null
2. Set it to a default `private IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> _weather = Enumerable<WeatherForecast>.Empty();`.

In general you load data in `OnInitializedAsync`.  However, you have to do it in `OnParametersSetAsync` if you are changing say the id of of record dynamically ( with next or previous buttons).  Your `OnParametersSetAsync` needs to save and test the ID parameter every time the component renders and reload if it changes.

[This may be a little contentious, but I'll happy to have a discussion] You should not change the component's state in `OnAfterRenderAsync`.  It's name tells you all you need to know.  It's for running stuff after the render process is complete, not for doing stuff that then needs to kick off the render process again to reflect the changed state.

All data loading can be done in a properly structured `OnInitialized/OnParametersSet` sequence.  Only use `OnAfterRender` for JSInterop stuff.

Comment: Thank you & I'm following your advice there, with one caveat. In `OnInitializedAsync` if I am given a bad parameter in the url, my code for making a popup visible on the page I call in `OnAfterRenderAsync` so it displays after the page under it is fully rendered. Is that a bad practice?

Comment: If you're using a JS popup then yes, run it in `OnAfterRenderAsync`.  If it's a Blazor generated popup then maybe use a flag to tell the UI to show it in the render event.  Anything in `OnAfterRenderAsync` that mutates the state of the component requires a new render event to show the changes. Do you want an example?

Comment: It's not a never rule, just do it rarely, and only when you can't do things more elegantly as part of the normal render process.

Answer (score 1):

You should generally load data within `OnInitializedAsync`. This method is only called once – when the page/component is being initialized for the very first time.

Sometimes, you may need to wait for initialization to actually load data. For example, if you have a component with certain data in it, and you use that data to fetch the correct information. In that case, you should load the data within `OnAfterRender`/`OnAfterRenderAsync`.

Generally, it doesn't matter. If your data loads fast enough, there is no realistic difference between where you load it. However, you should note that the `OnAfterRender` (and it's asynchronous option) come with a parameter `bool firstRender`. This lets you know whether the page/component has already been rendered before.

For example:

```cs
override protected OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
{
    if (firstRender)
    {
        // Load data in here
    }
}
```

This method is called after every single render (after event handlers, `StateHasChanged` is called, etc). But if you use the `firstRender` argument, you can check if this is the very first time the component has rendered – this is where you want to load the data (if you choose to load it in here).

Generally, I recommend that you load the data while the component is being initialized. If certain data can be loaded after the first contentful paint, then using `OnAfterRender` would be a good option for "lazy loading".