# OnAfterRenderAsync working on local but not on the server

Tags: asp.net, blazor, blazor-server-side

I created an web app with "Blazor Server Application" template in Visual Studio.

I found out that I need to use `protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)` to load data (and adding html elements to the page) without delaying load of website.

It worked fine when I was debugging, but when I put it on an Ubuntu server, setup nginx and open the website, it showed up, but data wasn't loaded. After a bit of testing I found that OnAfterRenderAsync() wasn't being called at all.

I tried to use OnInitializedAsync instead. It is being called normally, but I don't think I can use it, because then website is waiting for data to load.

I'm using `Index.razor` file + code-behind `Index.razor.cs` file.

My `Index.razor` have this:

```cs
@foreach (var serverHtml in ServerHtmls)
{
    @serverHtml
}
```

My code looks like this:
https://pastebin.com/K5NQPx9P

## PS

I created a clean Blazor Server app and runned it on Ubuntu.

On this page, there is a "Counter" and it doesn't even work when I run it on the server!
So there is a problem with the real-time functions when I'm running it on server. What's going on?

Code from PasteBin:

```cs
protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
   {
       if (!firstRender) return;
 
       Servers = new()
    {
        "1", "2"
    };
 
    foreach (var server in Servers)
    {
        await LoadAndAddServerAsync(server);
    }
   }
 
private async Task LoadAndAddServerAsync(string server)
{
    var serverResponse = await LoadServerDataAsync(server);
 
    List<string> premiumServers = new()
    {
        "1"
    };
 
    if (serverResponse.IsSuccess)
    {
        var motd = serverResponse.Motd;
        var icon = serverResponse.Icon;
 
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(icon))
        {
            icon = "/images/default-icon.webp";
        }
 
        bool premium = premiumServers.Contains(serverResponse.Server);
        string premiumClass = string.Empty;
        string premiumClass2 = string.Empty;
        if (premium)
        {
            premiumClass = " golden";
            premiumClass2 = " golden-text";
        }
 
        string serverHtml = $@"
               <div class=""col-sm-6"">
                   <div class=""content"">
                       <div class=""card{premiumClass}"">
                           <div>
                               <h1 class=""card-title{premiumClass2}"">
                                   {serverResponse.Server}
                               </h1>
                           </div>
                           <div>
                               <img class=""server-icon"" src=""{icon}"" alt=""..."" height=""80"" width=""80""/>
                           </div>
                           <div>
                               <p>
                                   {motd}
                               </p>
                           </div>
                       </div>
                   </div>
               </div>";
 
        ServerHtmls.Add(new MarkupString(serverHtml));
        StateHasChanged();
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Error: {serverResponse.Server}:\n{serverResponse.Exception.Message}");
    }
}
 
 
private async Task<ServerResponse> LoadServerDataAsync(string server)
{
    try
    {
        var timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2);
        var cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource(timeout);
        var cancellationToken = cancellationTokenSource.Token;
 
        string response = await _client.GetStringAsync("https://api" + server, cancellationToken);
 
        JObject json = JObject.Parse(response);
 
        // load and return data
    }
}
```

My nginx file looks like this:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name *domain*;

    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/origin.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/origin.key;

    location / {
        proxy_pass         https://localhost:5001;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   Connection keep-alive;
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

        proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   Connection "Upgrade";
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you enable websockets? Do you get any errors in the browser dev tools console?

Comment: [Polite] Why are you doing it this way rather than getting the data in `OnInitializdAsync` and then looping through the retrieved list.  Am I missing something?  "I tried to use OnInitializedAsync instead. It is being called normally, but I don't think I can use it, because then website is waiting for data to load."  Why not?  What makes this different from `FetchData`?

Comment: No, i don't have errors in browser console. Only things like "connected to blazor". I added my nginx file to the post. @MisterMagoo

Comment: _"I tried to use OnInitializedAsync instead. It is being called normally"_ == problem solved.

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis I'm sorry, but I don't understand. What fetchdata?

Comment: @HH did you read entire post? If I put my code into OnInitializedAsync, website doesn't load until all the data and html elements get added.

Comment: @HH? I know that it works well in the OnAfterRenderAsync, because I've been using this a long time. The website loads and only after the data gets loaded. Also, as I wrote in edit, there is some problem with the "blazor-editing-page-after-load", so I need to fix that.

Comment: @Nortia - see this question and answers [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76442472/blazor-should-i-read-in-my-data-in-oninitializedasync-or-onafterrenderasync/76443491#76443491 ] by @HH and myself on why you should normally not put data loading code in `OnAfterRenderAsync`.  Basically you're running the whole process twice, when there's normally no need.  `FetchData` is the Weather Forecast page in the default template that shows how to load data during the normal `OnInitialized{Async}/OnParametersSet{Async}` cycle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a Cloudflare's fault...

To be specific, "Auto Minify" option enabled caused the issue. When I disabled it, everything started to work.

Comment: Make sure to vote your answer as THE answer when that option unlocks for you.  This could be a real gotcha for someone else.