Blazor website work well on localhost but not so well on the server
I have this bit of code in my Home.razor file in my Blazor website:
protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
{
    if (!firstRender)
        return;
    Console.WriteLine("Got here");
    
}

I get the "Got here" output in the console when running it on Localhost but the output doesn't appear when I push it to the server.
I used dotpeek to look at the dll 'projectServer.Client.dll' and I see that the code is there. It's just not executing it for some reason when it's deployed to production.
My render mode is InteractiveAuto: <HeadOutlet @rendermode="@InteractiveAuto" />
Can you please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

which server you are using? By the way, is this case similar to yours? https://stackoverflow.com/a/1432088    and this one https://stackoverflow.com/a/9009837

I'm using Ubuntu as my server. No, I am not using IIS. The code works well on my system (Windows) in both debug and release mode but doesn't work at all on Ubuntu. Also, the problem is a bit deeper than what I wrote. I wrote that short bit of code to see if I could figure out a larger problem.

I must also add that I have checked the logs on the server. No error is being emitted.

Here is more information. The file I'm trying to debug can be found here https://sharefiles.virock.org/api/files/6628b2c86102510b836305b6 The webpage is https://linklasso.virock.org It doesn't even write the first log out. I don't know what to do.

No need for CORS. All files are obtained from the same origin.

Lol. I finally found the solution. Turns it, it was Cloudflare. The page I found the solution on was this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76697258/onafterrenderasync-working-on-local-but-not-on-the-server

How do I mark this question as a duplicate of that link?

you might post the link in the answer..

I found the answer here OnAfterRenderAsync working on local but not on the server
Turns out, Cloudflare's Auto Minify feature messes up blazor.web.js which in turn messes up the website.
