# Render a div in the blazor app after rendering another div

Tags: c#, .net, blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly

I have a scenario, in which I am loading data from db and then adding that to the div, I need to extend another div based on the height of the first div. I am trying with the `OnAfterRenderAsync`.

```
protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
{
    if (!firstRender && _isLoaded)
    {
        await DisplayOtherContent();
        StateHasChanged();
    }

    await base.OnAfterRenderAsync(firstRender);
}
```

So basically after rendering db data, I am calling `DisplayOtherContent` method, which is successfully adding html data in the HTML dom, I can see that in the inspect element but I can't see that on the html page.

Comment: Why not use css FlexBox making two items the same size inside a container is trivial. Without more details we do not have much to work on.

Comment: That code looks like it's going to loop forever. Add more details.

Comment: This code tells us nothing.  In all likelihood `DisplayOtherData` should be part of  `OnInitialized/OnParameterSet`  - Can you provide a [MRE] to demonstrate what you want to do.  See this https://stackoverflow.com/a/76443491/13065781

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am getting some data from the server and render that to the page and after the loading of that data, I wanted to set the height of some divs. so after trying different stuff at least something works.

```
protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
{
    if (_isLoaded)
    {
        await DisplayOtherContent();
        await InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
    }

    await base.OnAfterRenderAsync(firstRender);
}
```

Initially I was making the dynamic html in the string variable and render that string variable as a Markup HTML similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51585301/4727492). In this approach, I was able to get that html in the inspect element but it's not rendering on the page.

Later, I made changes and instead of generating dynamic html, I was calculating how much length I needed to extend in the html in the variable and then looping through that variable in the .razor view to generate that html. so for example, after getting data I set the variable **_isloaded**, and after rendering of that data, I calculated value of **_NoOfTime** in the **OnAfterRenderAsync** method and then using the loop I am able to make the html works.

```
        if (_isLoaded)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < _NoOfTime; i++)
            {
                // html code
            }
        }
```