My blazor page is executed twice when I need to execute just one time
I dont know why but the page /Generador/VerificarEmail/EncriptedEmailAndName is executed twice. ChatGPT suggested me to put all the code as async, so I did that but the page is still executing twice.
The page is to verify an email when a new user try to register in my web page and the link to access is put in a email that I send to the future user
Do anyone know where is the issue?
Here is my Blazor page code
@page "/Generador/VerificarEmail/{EncriptedEmailAndName}"

@using FiyiStackWeb2.Areas.Generator.AccountBack.Entities;
@using FiyiStackWeb2.Areas.Generator.AccountBack.Repositories;
@inject AccountRepository accountRepository;
@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager;

<PageTitle>Verificar email - FiyiStack</PageTitle>

<FiyiStackWeb2.Components.Layout.NavBarHome></FiyiStackWeb2.Components.Layout.NavBarHome>

<div class="page-header align-items-start min-vh-100"
     style="background-image: url('/img/FiyiStackWeb2/Generador-Crear-Cuenta.png');"
     loading="lazy">
    <span class="mask bg-gradient-dark opacity-6"></span>
    <div class="container my-auto">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-8 mx-auto">
                <div class="card z-index-0">
                    <div class="card-header p-0 position-relative mt-n4 mx-3 z-index-2">
                        <div class="bg-gradient-success shadow-success border-radius-lg py-3 pe-1">
                            <h4 class="text-white font-weight-bolder text-center mt-2 mb-0">
                                Verificar correo
                            </h4>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        @if (Message != "")
                        {
                            @((MarkupString)Message)
                        }
                        <div class="text-center">
                            <button type="button" class="btn bg-gradient-dark w-100 my-4 mb-2">
                                <i class="fas fa-door-open fa-xl"></i>
                                Login
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<FiyiStackWeb2.Components.Layout.FooterHome></FiyiStackWeb2.Components.Layout.FooterHome>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public string EncriptedEmailAndName { get; set; } = "";

    public string Message { get; set; } = "";

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        try
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(EncriptedEmailAndName))
            {
                Message = $@"<div class=""alert alert-warning text-white font-weight-bold"" role=""alert"">
                                Código encriptado para validar no proporcionado
                            </div>";
                return;
            }

            Account? AccountToVerify = await accountRepository.GetByEncriptedEmailAndNameAsync(EncriptedEmailAndName);

            if (AccountToVerify == null)
            {
                Message = $@"<div class=""alert alert-warning text-white font-weight-bold"" role=""alert"">
                                Cuenta inexistente
                            </div>";
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                if (AccountToVerify.IsEmailVerified == true)
                {
                    Message = $@"<div class=""alert alert-warning text-white font-weight-bold"" role=""alert"">
                                Esta cuenta ya se encuentra verificada
                            </div>";
                    return;
                }
                else
                {
                    AccountToVerify.IsEmailVerified = true;

                    await accountRepository.UpdateAsync(AccountToVerify);

                    Message = $@"<div class=""alert alert-warning text-white font-weight-bold"" role=""alert"">
        Cuenta verificada correctamente
    </div>";
                }
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Failure failure = new()
                {
                    Active = true,
                    DateTimeCreation = DateTime.Now,
                    DateTimeLastModification = DateTime.Now,
                    UserCreationId = 1,
                    UserLastModificationId = 1,
                    EmergencyLevel = 1,
                    Comment = "",
                    Message = ex.Message,
                    Source = ex.Source,
                    StackTrace = ex.StackTrace
                };

            await failureRepository.AddAsync(failure);
        }
        finally
        {
            //Re-render the page to show ScannedText
            await InvokeAsync(() => StateHasChanged()).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
    }
}


What Render mode are you using and where have you set Interactivity?  Server/WebAssembly/Auto  and Global/Per Page/Component.

@MrCakaShaunCurtis Sir, I have this one in App.razor: <Routes @rendermode=RenderMode.InteractiveServer />. What type should I use?

Have you checked that the OnInitializedAsync method is not being called more than once by using logging, check for any state changes that might trigger re-renders, and ensure there are no navigation issues. Also check the application log as well.

ChatGPT :)...your first issue. Pre-rendering is enabled by default if you're using NET8. So OnInitalizedAsync() will be called twice. You can either turn it off globally in App.razor, move your repo calls into the OnAfterRenderAsync() method, or use PersistentComponentState to persist.

@GHDevOps, I finally used that method that you mention, OnAfterRenderAsync(). Thanks

If the page is rendering twice it's because you are navigating to it from a SSR page, and this is the first page loaded by the SPA, or you are doing a force render on a Navigate to event.
In either case you can either disable prerendering on the page or use this pattern to short-circuit the pre-render.
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Home</PageTitle>

@if(_isPreRender)
{
    <div class="alert alert-warning">Pre Rendering</div>
    return;
}

<div class="alert alert-success">Interactive Render</div>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.

@code {
    [CascadingParameter] private HttpContext? httpContext { get; set; }

    private bool _isPreRender => httpContext is not null;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        if (_isPreRender)
        {
            return;
        }

        // Fake some async operations
        await Task.Yield();
    }
}

Also update this line:
await InvokeAsync(() => StateHasChanged()).ConfigureAwait(false);

To this keep it simple version:
await InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);

ComponentBase.InvokeAsync provides a way to invoke the provided delegate on the SynchronisationContext.  In this case that's StateHasChanged, which must be run in the SC.  ConfigureAwait(false) says run it anywhere [normally on the threadpool], I don't care.  Not true.

Thanks a lot sir! I tried your code and runs perfectly, anyway, I finally used OnAfterRenderAsync() to avoid executing twice the page

While using OnAfterRenderAsync seems the logical answer it isn't.  See the following two questions and answers that explain why - https://stackoverflow.com/a/78723214/13065781 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76442472/blazor-should-i-read-in-my-data-in-oninitializedasync-or-onafterrenderasync.
